# How to verify element/text is present in dropdown list using selenium java

Tags: selenium

How to verify element/text is present in drop down list using selenium java

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("airlineid"))).selectByVisibleText("Delta");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using the `Select` class.
To get the selected option that is visible:

```
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("airlineid"));
WebElement option = select.getFirstSelectedOption();
String selectedValueInDropDown = option.getText();
```

To get all the options:

```
Boolean found = false;

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("..."));
Select select = new Select(element);
List<WebElement> allOptions = select.getOptions();
for(int i=0; i<allOptions.size(); i++) {
    if(alloptions[i].Equals("your_option_text")) {
        found=true;
        break;
    }
}
if(found) {
    System.out.println("Value exists");
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur inpts, i need not to check the selected text/value....i want whether the text/value is present or not in drop downlist

Comment: Then the second part of the code is doing exactly that. if the `found` variable is `true` then your value exists in the drop down list.

Comment: Great to hear. In this case please accept the answer so that this question no longer remains open and other facing the same problems as you can see what they can do to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know java, but i can give you code in c#, you can modify if as per java methods and coding standards

Solution1

```
IWebElement dropDownElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("continents"));
        if (dropDownElement.Text.Contains("the value you are looking for here"))
        {
            // value is present in drop down
        }
        else
        {
            // value is not present
        }
```

Solution2

```
IList<IWebElement> optionsofDropDown = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='continents']/option"));

foreach (IWebElement optionVal in optionsofDropDown)
{
   if (optionVal.Text == "the value you are looking for here")
   {
       //value available in drop down
        break;
    }
    else
    {
       //value available in drop down
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me :

```
Select select = new Select(select_drop_down);
List<WebElement> all_options = select.getOptions();
boolean found = false;

for (WebElement we : all_options) { 
    if (facility.equalsIgnoreCase(we.getAttribute("value"))) {
        select.selectByValue(facility);
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```